# How can can i insert a user with profile picture using Blazor-server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want the user to upload his picture when he registers his information.
The thing is when the user uploads his image.. should automatically create a folder with his ID to be like this wwwroot/images/UserID/fadi.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Basically: you really shouldn't. The wwwroot is for static assets used by the application. You're using server-side, so in theory it might be possible but that's not what the folder is meant for. An alternative method like AWS would be preferred, but if you can't do that (either because of payment requirements or other complications) I would suggest saving the image to your database. One way to do this would be to base64 encode the image and save it that way. I'm not going to give an example of that here, there are plenty available elsewhere. One such example is [this](https://morioh.com/p/7525c671e52d).

Comment: I did save them in the server (SQL EXPRESS) in the first place, but it became very slow.. what do you think?

Comment: I can't really comment on what exactly might cause the sloweness, as it could be quite a lot of different things. The first thing that comes to mind however is probably file size. How large are the images and how many do you save? If it's just a user picture, you don't need the file to be much larger then 50kb-200kb. Another thing that helps (if you use entity framework) is making a separate table for images and linking it to the users through an ID. This would allow you to fetch multiple users without having to fetch images.

Comment: Adding to what @Nijenhof said. As your using server. Its not hard after uploading the image to resize it to say 48x48 pixels for User profile Icon purposes.  Then the base64 encoding will not be large.